# Ubuntu 23.10 certain windows are garbled. Can't install on Athlon 220GE

Tags: graphics

When booting off a live USB drive to install Ubuntu, the Desktop and certain Gnome windows (Terminal, Nautilus) show up correctly, but others (Ubuntu install window and Firefox) do not. This seems like a compositor or driver issue because when I move windows around in front of the installer window, window remnants blur over the installer window.

[image: Good terminal window, but bad installer window]

This is a basic computer running the 220GE's onboard Vega graphics and 16GB of RAM.

I've looked at the dmesg logs, and can't find any odd logs anywhere. When starting up in "Safe Graphics Mode" the issues are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Install it using Safe Graphics mode.

After finding that I could use Safe Graphics mode to run Ubuntu from the flash drive, I installed it. On starting it from the internal drive it seems to work well with no garbling. This may be due to updates or some oddness with the Live image. This answer is being typed from the same machine running Ubuntu with no issue.